# Template deduction error binding QComboBox::currentIndexChanged to lambda

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, compiler-errors, qobject

I am *100% sure* that this is a not-enough-coffee problem, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. This code is attempting to connect a `QComboBox`'s slot to a lambda (something I've done many times and yet...):

```c++
#include <QComboBox>

static void somewhere () {
    QComboBox *cb = ...;
    QObject::connect(cb, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, [cb](int){
    });
}
```

However, this fails to compile with a string of template deduction failures ([full output here](https://pastebin.com/vardkMA7)) ultimately resulting in:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QComboBox*&, 
    <unresolved overloaded function type>, somewhere(QComboBox*)::<lambda(int)>)'
```

This is Qt 5.15.2, compiled with gcc 8.1 (MinGW 8.1.0 64-bit), in C++17 mode.

[`QComboBox` docs confirm](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) the signal has an `int` parameter:

```
void QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int index)
```

[`QObject` docs confirm](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-4) this form of `connect` exists as a static member:

```
connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, Functor functor)
```

What am I missing here... ?

Comment: I *know* this is something stupid... but I've been banging my head on the wall for like 30 minutes... so go easy on me, heh.

Comment: @chehrlic Ah ha! Indeed it is. **THANK YOU!** I'll close it with a link now. Finally, I can rest, haha...